# Parse tranformations data

Tags: 0x

I want to make a multi-swap smart contract in which each swap will swap the amount obtained with the last swap.

For that I'll need to modify the amount hardcored in the transformations array data.

Are there a way to parse these data to modify the amount to be trade, and then encode it to have the update transformations array with the amount receive with the previous swap ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So long as you're only doing sells, you can try passing in `shouldSellEntireBalance=true` for each quote. This will try to sell the minimum of the taker's balance and allowance granted to the `allowanceTarget`. Just make sure your contract adjusts the allowance before each swap if you don't want to spend its entire balance.

Comment: Thank you, it works for the transactions that I retreive directly from your API but in some cases I have 0x txs returned by others APIs (for example, DODO API sometimes return a tx that have callback data to your contract) so I can't specify the shouldSellEntireBalance value. In this case, are there a way to parse the transformation data to modify the amount to set uint256(-1) in sell amount (in addition to the inputTokenAmount value that I can already modify in the parse tx) ?

Comment: Technically yes, but it's pretty hairy and changes frequently so I wouldn't recommend it.